# debug in asp.net core code (Visual studio 2019)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I just got into asp programming. This is a pilot project.

The project is built with asp .net core.

Shows me errors , how to fix the errors?

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup()
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
                Configuration = builder.Build();
            }
            
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
            }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }

                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                    {
                        var msg = Configuration["message"];
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(msg);
                    });
                });
            }
            // Entry point for the application. 
            public static void Main(string[] args) = 7gt; WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);

        }
    }
```

Errors:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1002  ; expected  FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1519  Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1519  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS8124  Tuple must contain at least two elements.   FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0501  'Startup.Main(string[])' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial  FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1007 The name 'gt' does not exist in the current context.    FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1007 The name 'WebApplication.Run' does not exist in the current context.   FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1007 The name 'Run' does not exist in the current context.  FirstAppDemo

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1007 The name 'args' does not exist in the current context.  FirstAppDemo

What should I do?

Help me please

Comment: a) please include error messages ***as text*** b) it seems most of them can be fixed by learning to use proper syntax

Comment: All the errors are mostly related to the last line, but I do not understand that line, please help

Comment: Forgive me for these bugs, I understand what you mean and I will not let these bugs be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Startup class inside another Startup class. That seems to be one of the problems.

[image: Wrong]

That doesn't work because of the reason expressed in the errors. Remove one of the Startup classes (outer or inner)

Comment: but very bug in this code?